# Get Key code at value change listener of JSF iceface

Tags: jsf, icefaces

I have one autocomplete input text in that i want key code on valueChangeListener as we can get it in javascript by using event.getKeyCode like that..I m using jsf 1.2 and icefaces 1.7.2.

I want enter key code on valuechangelistener.

```
<ice:selectInputText id="AutoCmpTxt11" rows="10" width="300" 
valueChangeListener="#createJournalVoucherBean.changeDebitAccNameValueChangedListener}"
value="#{createJournalVoucherBean.debitAccount.name}" partialSubmit="true"
autocomplete="true">
```

here listener as follow.

```
 public void changeDebitAccNameValueChangedListener (ValueChangeEvent event) throws InterruptedException {
    String searchWord = ((String) event.getNewValue()).trim().toUpperCase();
    //Here I want event.getkeycode like that.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you need it for? You already have the `searchWord`. If all what you want is to get the last character for some reason, then just use [`String#charAt()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29).

```
char lastChar = searchWord.charAt(searchWord.length() - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here below is sample code for enter-key detection.

You can do it for other key-press events as required.

```
public void changeDebitAccNameValueChangedListener (ValueChangeEvent event) throws InterruptedException {

String searchWord = ((String) event.getNewValue()).trim().toUpperCase();

        //-- Code for key detection

         keyPressedEvent(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());

        //--
}


    private void keyPressedEvent(FacesContext facesContext) {

                        try {
                            Map requestParemeterMap = facesContext.getExternalContext()
                                    .getRequestParameterMap();
                           KeyEvent keyEvent = new KeyEvent(this , requestParemeterMap);

                            if (keyEvent.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.CARRIAGE_RETURN) {
                                // do your custom processing
                            }

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
}
```